# C++ Trie search performance

Tags: c++, performance, search, trie

So I made a trie that holds quite a large amount of data, my search algorithm is quite fast but I wanted to see if anyone had any insight as to how I could make it any faster.

```
    bool search (string word)
{
    int wordLength = word.length();
    node *current = head;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<wordLength; ++i)
    {
            if (current->child[((int)word[i]+(int)'a')] == NULL)
                    return false;
            else
                    current = current->child[((int)word[i]+(int)'a')];
    }
    return current->is_end;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good performance-wise, except these tidbits:

- Declare the function parameter as `const string&` (instead of just `string`), to avoid unnecessary copying.
- You could extract the common subexpression `current->child[((int)word[i]+(int)'a')]` in front of the `if`, to avoid repetition and make the code slightly smaller, but any compiler worth its salt will do that optimization for you anyway.

---

"Style" suggestions:

- What if `word` contains character below 'a' (such as capital letter, digit, punctuation mark, new line etc...)? You'll need to **validate** input to avoid accessing the wrong memory location and crashing. Also shouldn't this be `-(int)'a'` instead of `+` (I'm assuming you just want to support a limited set of characters: 'a' and above)?
- Declare `wordLength` as `size_t` (or better yet `auto`), but this is not important for strings of any practical length (might even hurt the performance slightly if `size_t` is greater than `int`). Ditto for `i`.

Comment: I use + (int) a because there are characters with values below a

Comment: @that_guy: in that case you shouldn't add anything to `word[i]`. Decide on the valid range, and (optionally) shift the range to start at 0 by subtracting the lowest value in the range from `word[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool search (string word)
```

Calling this function, string `word` will be copied,
type of function below will be faster.

```
bool search (const string &word)
```

or

```
bool search (const char *word)
```